# How to change single column color in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

How to change a single column color in tableau?

I have five columns and I need to change the color for a single column.

```
Measure Names   Month of Month Date Measure Values
Total Sales January 34,512,343.63
Total Costs January 34,343,434
Difference  January 168,909.630000003
Fees    January 5,678
Difference w Fees Added January 174,587.630000003
Total Sales February    3,423,534.21
Total Costs February    2,323,232
Difference  February    1,100,302.21
Fees    February    5,678
Difference w Fees Added February    1,105,980.21
Total Sales March   34,534,533.33
Total Costs March   22,222,222
Difference  March   12,312,311.33
Fees    March   6,789
Difference w Fees Added March   12,319,100.33
Total Sales April   333,830,456.44
Total Costs April   23,232,323
Difference  April   310,598,133.44
Fees    April   6,789
Difference w Fees Added April   310,604,922.44
Total Sales May 1,000,000
Total Costs May 750,000
Difference  May 250,000
Fees    May 6,767
Difference w Fees Added May 256,767
Total Sales June    1,000,000
Total Costs June    750,000
Difference  June    250,000
Fees    June    6,767
Difference w Fees Added June    256,767
Total Sales July    1,000,000
Total Costs July    750,000
Difference  July    250,000
Fees    July    6,767
Difference w Fees Added July    256,767
Total Sales August  1,000,000
Total Costs August  750,000
Difference  August  250,000
Fees    August  6,767
Difference w Fees Added August  256,767
Total Sales September   1,000,000
Total Costs September   750,000
Difference  September   250,000
Fees    September   6,767
Difference w Fees Added September   256,767
Total Sales October 1,000,000
Total Costs October 750,000
Difference  October 250,000
Fees    October 6,767
Difference w Fees Added October 256,767
Total Sales November    1,000,000
Total Costs November    750,000
Difference  November    250,000
Fees    November    6,767
Difference w Fees Added November    256,767
Total Sales December    1,000,000
Total Costs December    750,000
Difference  December    250,000
Fees    December    6,767
Difference w Fees Added December    256,767
Total Sales All 414,300,867.61
Total Costs All 88,121,211
Difference  All 326,179,656.61
Fees    All 79,070
Difference w Fees Added All 326,258,726.61
```

Comment: question is not clear, you need to mention which column and what is possible case to change the colour

Answer (score 1):

Tableau 10.2 introduced the ability to colour individual elements of a chart using individual legends.

Drag 'Measure Values' to the Colour mark, then right click and select '*Use Separate Legends*'.

You'll then see a colour legend for each element, and you can change the colour of each independently. If you just want to colour one column then set the others to black, for example.

[image]

Comment: Hi..Thanks for the reply...but I am unable to see the option "use separate legends". I am using 10.5 V

Comment: Perhaps it is the measure you are trying to colour on, which are you using? Can you share a sample workbook?